# intellij idea selecting color for ui

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I am using Dracula theme on my IntelliJ idea and I see the dark font on the Find in Path, Tex to find box and search results text which is really difficult to read.
[image]

How can I customize these colors

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html

Answer (score 0):

You can update the colors in the `Editor` Settings. Go to `Preferences -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> General`.

On the right pane select `Text -> Default Text` from the list of expandable options. Update the properties as required.

[image]